# Does shallow nesting work for resources nesting 2 levels deep?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have comments belonging to answers, and answers belonging to questions.

I know I shouldn't be nesting 2 levels deep, but would shallow nesting work for this?

```
shallow do
  resources :questions do
    resources :comments
    resources :answers
  end
end
```

Would this allow all the paths to be executable?

Answer (score 0):

Shallow nesting is **specifically designed** for resources nesting 2 levels deep.

Read the [guide, 2.7.2 Shallow Nesting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) (scroll down a bit), and look at the examples and their generated routes tables. Decide if that works for you.